# Erro ao configurar ambiente Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, netbeans

Boa tarde, pessoal
Estou aprendendo Ruby on Rails na faculdade e para praticar em casa estou tentando instalar e configurar o ambiente no meu pc, porem sem sucesso.
Instalei o NetBeans e o MySQL Server e quando vou criar um novo projeto Ruby on Rails no Netbeans o seguinte erro ocorre:

[image: Alguem saberia solucionar esse erro?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente o que vc tem é uma versão mais antiga do Netbeans, e você está tentando criar um projeto com uma versão antiga do Rails (2.3.8). O Netbeans nas versões mais recentes deixou de suportar Rails oficialmente. Se você pretende usar uma IDE, sugiro que use o [RubyMine](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/). Ele é pago, mas você consegue facilmente uma versão gratuita para estudantes. Você pode usar ainda o Atom, Sublime, VIM ou Textmate.

E já que você está começando agora, use o Rails 4.